# How to get constants declared in a class as a map

Tags: java, reflection, enums, constants

I am trying to find a way to access constants declared in a class, from outside the class as a map

```
public final class MyConstants {
    public static final MY_CONST_1 = "CONST_1";
    public static final MY_CONST_2 = "CONST_2";
    public static final MY_CONST_3 = "CONST_3";
    public static final MY_CONST_4 = "CONST_4";
}
```

My attempt is to get all constants declared in MyConstants in a map with name of the const as the key and value as the value

Comment: why not just implement a Map interface?

Comment: @Rishab Are you allowed to modify the class in any way? Because I think the simplest solution here is to convert the whole class to an `enum`.

Comment: Defining an enum is much more reliable than using reflection.

Comment: Thank you @VGR. I did end up converting that to enum. Which indeed is more easier and safer.

Comment: Thank you @Matthew. I did end up converting that to enum. Which indeed is more easier and safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `MyConstants` class is populated with `String` constants and you wanted a solution that involves reflection here is a simple way to do it:

```
public final class MyConstants {
    public static final String MY_CONST_1 = "CONST_1";
    public static final String MY_CONST_2 = "CONST_2";
    public static final String MY_CONST_3 = "CONST_3";
    public static final String MY_CONST_4 = "CONST_4";
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException
{
    MyConstants constants = new MyConstants();
    java.util.Map<String, String> map = new java.util.LinkedHashMap<>();
    Field[] fields = constants.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {
        map.put(field.getName(), (String) field.get(constants));
    }
    for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.printf("Key: %s, Value: %s%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Key: MY_CONST_1, Value: CONST_1
Key: MY_CONST_2, Value: CONST_2
Key: MY_CONST_3, Value: CONST_3
Key: MY_CONST_4, Value: CONST_4
```

However if you wanted a more advanced approach which is free of the more common pitfalls I would recommend using `Apache Commons Language library` and `FieldUtils#readField(Field, Object, boolean)` method that comes with it. I've written a utility method that will cast the object for your and throw appropriate exceptions making it easier to debug. You can find the method in my [ReflectionUtils class](https://github.com/yooksi/commons/blob/master/src/main/java/io/yooksi/commons/util/ReflectionUtils.java) as part of my personal [Commons](https://github.com/yooksi/commons) project on Github.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your design is not right , and the constants shouldn't be constants , but enum with additional value ? 
wouldn't that fit your needs more ?